# I am using react navigation v5 .I have stack navigation in Drawer navigation. How can i get the initial screen every time i click the drawer item?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

My Router

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import Cart from './Cart';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Product from './Product';
import Search from './Search';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const SubPart = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Product" component={Product} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Contact" component={Contact} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
class DrawerMain extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="SubPart" component={SubPart} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default DrawerMain;
```

When i click the subpart i get about screen and then i go the Product screen in stack screen and from there if i go the cart drawer screen and then click the subpart drawer item i get the product screen not the about screen.How i can i get the about screen every time i click the subpaert item drawer?

Comment: You can use <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="About" >

Comment: I tried that . I was getting same result @azwar_akbar

Comment: Have you try with: navigation.navigate('About')  ?

Comment: You can check this page: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator